# Login Error when using library googleplay-api

Tags: android, python, download, google-play

I am using the [googleplay-api](https://github.com/NeroBurner/googleplay-api) module to download sample Android apps for my research project. In the past, I could use this library using my GMail account name, password, and Android ID/Google Service Framework (GSF). But just few days a ago, I got an error as below when I ran the same code. I am wondering if anybody else using this library gets the same problem. Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 36, in <module>
    api.login(config['GOOGLE_LOGIN'], config['GOOGLE_PASSWORD'], config['AUTH_TOKEN'])
  File "/Users/ChihWu/Desktop/test/googleplay-api/googleplay_api/googleplay.py", line 179, in login
    raise LoginError("server says: " + params["error"])
googleplay_api.googleplay.LoginError: u'server says: UNKNOWN_ERR'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to login to play.google site and open any application. 
Do you, by any chance, have "You don't have any devices" error message? Instead of "This app is compatible with your device".